# Why the volume of a region is not a diffeomorphism invariant? (LQG)

Tags: general-relativity, volume, loop-quantum-gravity, diffeomorphism-invariance

In loop quantum gravity, the [volume operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_operator) for a given region is not a diffeomorphism invariant. But classically we know that volume is a scalar quantity under a diffeomorphism even if we take the full manifold or any region.

Comment: Volume is not invariant under a diffeomorphism, only under an isometry.

Comment: But the volume element in n-manifold is n-form which is a scalar quantity under any (passive or active diffeomorphism)

Comment: @ravjotsk n-forms are scalar quantities, but the components of the n-form who transform as a tensor. The volume element in a 4d- metric space (M,g) is: sqrt( det(g) )*d^4x which is a scalar quantity.

Comment: @o.nemoul My bad. I’ll remove my comment since it’s not useful. However I thought that the term scalars was used for tensors of rank zero and an n-form is an alternating tensor of covariant rank-n. Although the tensor itself as an object remains invariant under coordinate transformations, the fact that its components change means its not a scalar (which should have the same value no matter what coordinates you use)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you think that volume is not diffeo-invariant?

If the region moves along with the diffemorphisms (aka passive diffeomorphisms), the volume is invariant. In LQG, the volume is also invariant (if you disagree, please explain why).

If the region doesn't move with diffeomorphisms (aka active diffeomorphisms), the volume changes. That is because the region here is only a region in the coordinate space, which doesn't have a well-defined notion of volume. The same is also true in LQG.

LQG is really not different from General Relavitity when it comes to diffeomorphism invariance.

Comment: Volume is not invariant under Lorentz transformations (through the contractrion factor). If the diffeomorphism invariance is meant only for the 3d spacial submanifold(then volume would be invariant) of full diffeomorphism invariant for the 4d pseudo riemannanin manifold (then 3 volume.isnt invariantn): I have.no.idea.

Comment: @lalala Lorentz transformations are active diffeomorphisms. Volume is not invariant under those neither in GR or in LQG, as I said in my answer.

Comment: Ah now I see what you meant. I thought the passive/active wording.unusual so.I didnt really understood your point

Comment: @lalala but in LQG volume is also not invariant under the spatial diffeomorphism.

Comment: @SolenodonParadoxus if you mean that the fixed region is in the coordinates chart and not in the real manifold, i will agree with you. But why do we consider the region inside the coordinates system?

Comment: @SolenodonParadoxus. The volume operator for a fixed region in LQG is not invariant under diffeomorphism (active). I think the reason for that is the quantum state of space that the volume operator act on. This state is parameterized by a fixed graph G of smooth curves. Whene we act the volume operator of a region R on this state does not the same as if we do it for the transformed volume operator for the new region R'. Because the eigenvalues of the volume operator depend on the intersection points of the fixed region and the fixed nodes (intersection points of curves) of thegraph.

Comment: @o.nemoul if you consider a fixed region inside a coordinate chart, then the region is invariant under active diffeomorphisms (passive diffeomorphisms change the coordinates). The volume changes under those both in GR and LQG. If you consider a fixed region inside the physical space, it is invariant under passive diffeomorphisms (active diffeomorphisms change the physical fields inside your region). The volume is thus invariant both in GR and LQG. What else is there to say? Why do you think your question is specific to LQG?

Comment: @SolenodonParadoxus Yes, active diffeomorphisms change the physical fields inside your region. but it also changes the metric such that the volume remains unchanged under active diffeo.

Comment: @o.nemoul I meant the metric when I said "physical fields". No, your last sentence is not true. It is always possible to squash the whole galaxy into a ball in the coordinate space which prior to the diffeomorphism corresponded to an orange. The volume of your ball changes, because active diffeos change the physical content of the space inside it (the metric).

Comment: @SolenodonParadoxus the invariant action of GR consists from a scalar curvature and a volume element which also a scalar?

Comment: @o.nemoul nope, the volume element is a scalar density.

Comment: @SolenodonParadoxusthe components of the volume form is a tensor density, but the 4d volume is a 4-form and it is a scalar (I am talking about 4d-volume in GR) and since the scalar curavture is a scalar quantity then the 4d-volume must be invariant.

Comment: @o.nemoul what you really mean by that is that a volume of the given region doesn't change under passive diffeomorphisms. I completely agree with that. But active diffeomorphisms also move the region itself into a different one, thus changing the volume effectively. Which was the whole point of my answer.

Comment: @SolenodonParadoxus yes now i can see it. The physical manifold transforms to another one, then we have a transformation between metrics  by the pull back map, while the coordinates system remain unchanged. Changing the components of metric in the same coordinates system leads to a change in the volume. Thank you.

Comment: @o.nemoul you’re welcome, and don’t forget to accept my answer if you are satisfied with it.

Comment: @Solenodon Paradoxus How can i do it? I am a new member.